# Is "rescindication" a word?

Tags: single-word-requests

Base Word:

> **re·scind**
>
> *verb*
>
> revoke, cancel, or repeal.

Example: The rescidication of that law is ridiculous.

Am I making up a word here? Or is a real word despite spell checker and google? I suppose "rescinding" could be used, but that's present tense.

Comment: Please, laws are rescinded, not admissions to colleges. Yes, you are off the track, in the weeds.....rescinding is not present tense only. It is also a noun.

Comment: @armflare you can use 'rescind' only if Yale offered you a place, which you accepted, and then withdrew their offer. It is not equivalent to Yale rejecting your application.

Comment: But no past-tense use? Only something like "rescinded" or "rescinding"?

Comment: Julie is right. :) I have never heard of a college doing that. I have heard of an offer being rescinded.

Comment: Fine... I'll use a better example :P

Comment: For the past-tense you could say 'Yale *rescinded* my offer". Present-tense use could be: "Yale is currently *rescinding* my offer." *Rescindment* is the noun form. Take a look at some online dictionary definitions and examples of usage to familiarise yourself with the term.

Comment: It might create homophone problems with _resyndication_, as in "The resyndication of that guy's lousy editorial columns is ridiculous."

Comment: Stating that admissions offers, or admissions decisions, are rescinded but not admissions themselves is the sort of hairsplitting [up with which I shall not put](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001715.html). The likes of [Harvard rescind admissions](http://www.nytimes.com/1995/04/14/us/harvard-now-asking-if-would-be-student-who-killed-her-mother-then-lied-about-it.html) and so do the likes of [Terra State Community College](https://www.insidehighered.com/quicktakes/2015/12/09/ohio-community-college-settles-disability-suit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the noun of *rescind*, which can be **rescission** or **rescindment**.

> [rescission](https://www.google.com/search?q=rescidication%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=rescission) - the revocation, cancellation, or repeal of a law, order, or agreement. (Google)
>
> [rescindment](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/rescindment) - the doing away with something by formal action (MW)

Comment: Not exactly what I was after, but thanks for the alternate words.